# How to prevent a button from dimming its text when being touched?

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin, colors

I have a button with white text and blue background (created using Xamarin.Forms).

When I press it in iOS emulator, I noticed that the text gets darker and diffuses into the background. How to prevent this? I would like the text to stay white at all times. There is no such issue on Android.

Here is the gif video to show the problem (ignore the shadow effect, it was added later and it does not affect the issue):

http://i.imgur.com/QwYvhTu.gifv

Comment: I don't have knowledge about Xamarin, but I can say you have to set the title color of button to White (or) what ever you want, in normal state , highlighted state and in selected state.

Comment: Seemed like a good idea, but unfortunately did not work - I set the color to red for all the three button states to immediately notice the changes, but still the dimming is happening.

Comment: So you have normal, highlighted and disabled state
so have you written like this  ?

buttonRect.SetTitleColor (UIColor.LightGray, UIControlState.Normal);
buttonRect.SetTitleColor (UIColor.LightGray, UIControlState.Highlighted);
buttonRect.SetTitleColor (UIColor.LightGray, UIControlState.Disabled);

Comment: Yes, I have the following Xamarin code which should be equal to native iOS (unless there is a bug or something): http://i.imgur.com/FFcmu5y.png  and it still shows the same dimming: http://i.imgur.com/v7KhYX2.gifv

Comment: I think that if you use button type `Custom`, the button will not have that animation.

Comment: @dylansturg Thanks, I will try to find how to replace the default button with iOS Custom button correctly on Xamarin.

Comment: @dylansturg  Yes, that was it, I created a custom Xamarin.Forms renderer and told it to create UIButton with Custom type instead of default type, and now there is no text dimming when I tap the button.

Comment: @JustAMartin Great. Glad to hear you get it resolved.